# Image Resize C#,VB.NET Opensource Library

Tags: c#, .net, imaging

Any one point me on good direction on how to resize a jpg image to exactly particular size (Both File size and pixel size Ex. 148 x 72 px , 300 KB  ).

To Acheive this, Quality of images can be adjusted.

It may a .NET library /code but it should be free for commercial use / open source.

I want it in either C# or VB.NET as library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Graphics.DrawImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yws82c40.aspx) to resize the image.  Then you can adjust the quality by passing a parameter to the Bitmap.Save method ([more info](http://weblogs.asp.net/despos/archive/2004/01/12/57752.aspx#57762)).  I don't know how you can go from a file size to get the correct compression parameter.  You could always try multiple compression parameters until the file size matched what you needed.