# Manipulating / Resizing / Scaling an image in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, image, image-manipulation

Imagine I have a rectangle say 400px x 300px.  Then let’s say I want to load an image in that. All of this is very easy using [Sytem.Drawing.DrawImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage.aspx).

[Rectangle http://img576.imageshack.us/img576/2363/rectangle.gif](http://img576.imageshack.us/img576/2363/rectangle.gif)

But then I want to leave the left hand side as 300px but change the right hand side to 250 px. I can draw the box using 4 DrawLines but I don’t know how to squash the image into the new shape.  I want the right hand side of the shape to be 250, the left size 300 and the top and bottom 400px.

[Resized http://img85.imageshack.us/img85/3479/rectangle2.gif](http://img85.imageshack.us/img85/3479/rectangle2.gif)

I can’t use DrawImage as it expects the left and right sizes to be the same. Is there a way to manipulate the image into the new shape?

I've looked at [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144592/resizing-images-in-vb-net) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668318/image-resize-c-vb-net-opensource-library), but they only apply where the left and right hand side is equal.

Any thoughts on how to squash an image into a shape which did not have parallel sides?

(If it helps, I'm happy to sacrifice image quality to fit the right shape.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is non-trivial (but also very powerful).

@Heinzi is correct, the general class is called warp transformations.  What you're trying to do is specifically a *perspective transformation*.  At a high level, it involves running the individual coordinates through a transformation matrix to get their new positions, and then doing interpolation between pixel values based on the old and new locations.

[This](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/Transformations0412192005054803AM/Transformations04.aspx) article talks about some transformations, one of them being a sheer, so it might be helpful overall.  I'm not sure, I haven't read it closely.  In general, you want to google for something approximately like "c# image transformation" or "c# image perspective transform".

Depending on what you're planning on using it for, buying a library might be the best way to go about it, although there is a lot to learn about image manipulation by doing it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I work for Atalasoft.

Our DotImage product has a command called QuadrilateralWarpCommand that can do this.  It's in [DotImage Photo](http://atalasoft.com/products/dotimage).

Answer (score 1):

I did not find a solution to your problem, but I have some information which might help you along:

What you want is called a *warp transformation*.

As far as I know, the .net framework natively supports this kind of transformation only for a `GraphicsPath`, namely, the [GraphicsPath.Warp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb63t31a.aspx) method. Unfortunately, I don't think that this will help you, unless you are willing to redraw your image using a .net [GraphicsPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbkz3sfb.aspx) object.

If you need the transformation directly in the UI layer, your UI library might help: Silverlight, for example, includes the [PlaneProjection class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.planeprojection.aspx), which can be used for such effects; in WPF, the 3D engine might be useful for this (requiring more programming effort, through).